# gremlin shortestPath() with step

Tags: gremlin, shortest-path

where is the document about gremlin with step?
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#with-step
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/computer/traversal/step/map/ShortestPath.html
there is no example I can use.
I want to know all with-step option(like ShortestPath.edges-Direction.OUT) for shortestPath().
I found below

```
g.withComputer().V(xxx).shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.edges, Direction.OUT).with(ShortestPath.distance, 'cost').with(ShortestPath.target, hasId(bbb))
```

I want to know all option I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with()`-step is not really a "step". It is a step modulator. Its context is bound to the step that it is modifying and therefore you won't find "all the `with()` configurations" in one place. You can only find them in the documentation related to the steps that they modulate. Using `shortestPath()` as an example, note that if you look at the `shortestPath()` [step documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#shortestpath-step) all of the options are present.

You may also need to consult the documentation of your graph provider as they may provide their own configuration keys for certain steps which can help optimize or otherwise modify traversal operations.